# Implode all row values with specific Id's only

Tags: jquery, implode

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped data-table" id="data-table" style="display: table;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sr #</th>
            <th>Services</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="data">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" id="sr">1</td>
            <td align="center" id="items">Hotel</td>
            <td align="center" id="price">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="number" name="price" class="form-control Hotel price" value="0" min="0">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" id="sr">2</td>
            <td align="center" id="items">Umrah</td>
            <td align="center" id="price">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="number" name="price" class="form-control Umrah price" value="0" min="0">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" id="sr">3</td>
            <td align="center" id="items">Visa</td>
            <td align="center" id="price">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="number" name="price" class="form-control Visa price" value="0" min="0">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <label>Total Amount : </label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" align="center">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" id="total_amount" class="form-control" readonly="">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <label>Invoice Status : </label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <select class="form-control inv_status">
                        <option value="">--Select Status---</option>
                        <option value="Paid">Paid</option>
                        <option value="Partial">Partial</option>
                        <option value="Unpaid">Unpaid</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 partial" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="text" id="partial_am" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Partial Amount">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to implode all calues of rows under "Services" & "Price" headings in two different variables like this:

```
var services = Umrah,Hotel,Visa
var prices = 0,0,0
```

How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: Please take care to format your code correctly. It previously made no sense.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ IDs have to be unique, you have multiple duplicated IDs in your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you require you can use the `nth-child` selector to retrieve the required columns and then `map` to generate an array of the values in them. Try this:

```
var services = $('table tbody:eq(0) tr > td:nth-child(2)').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join(',');

var prices = $('table tbody:eq(0) tr > td:nth-child(3)').map(function() {
    return $(this).find('input').val();
}).get().join(',');

console.log(services);
console.log(prices);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ewc7dnyb/)

Alternatively, you can manually create the arrays and update them in a single loop through the rows of the table:

```
var services = [];
var prices = [];

$('table tbody:eq(0) tr').each(function() {
    var $row = $(this);
    services.push($row.find('> td:nth-child(2)').text());
    prices.push($row.find('> td:nth-child(3) input').val());
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ewc7dnyb/1/)

Finally, as spotted by @Michael, you have several duplicate `id` attributes assigned to multiple elements in your HTML. This is invalid as `id` must be unique within a `document`. If you need to group elements use classes instead.

Comment: Awesome ! It Worked ! Thanks Alot Dude :)

Comment: One Thing More Bro :) , How Can i Make a Global Variable In JQuery?

Comment: Don't. Global variables are a bad idea.

Comment: So How Can Use These Created Variables In Another Function?

Comment: Pass them to the function as parameters.

Comment: Can You Show Me A Demo Code?

Comment: Can You Join Me In Chat?